# How to arrange watchkit buttons in a circle inside a group?

Tags: objective-c, iphone, xcode7, watchkit

I'm developing a watchkit application. I have six buttons and I wish to place them in a circular manner.

How to achieve this?

Please help me with the idea.

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since I used WatchKit... but as far as I know you can place groups into groups into groups. Use 4 Groups. On the first and last Group place one button each into the center. On the second and third group place two groups of the same size that fill the 'supergroup' together. Set the alignment of the left one to left and of the right one to right. Place a Button into each.
Now they should be in a circle.

Comment: Thanks! i will surely see to it.